# Is it possible produce .djvu files from LaTeX directly?

Tags: tools

I see some .djvu files with worked links, side bar table of content and I can select/search text inside document (with WinDjvu viewer).

How produce .djvu file from LaTeX files?

**PS.** @Paulo Cereda. Thanks for suggestion. `pdf2djvu` have build for Windows and present in Debian repo. And do job right!

Comment: Isn't dvju for scanned documents? For Latex-generated content wouldn't a PDF serve just as well, if not better?

Comment: It is true. But this format is open and allow links and text selection/search. Also document size can be less then in .pdf, especially for documents with large amount of images.

Comment: PDF is an ISO standard. I doubt the djvu documents can be smaller than PDF given that the latter supports JBIG2 and JPEG2000. Frankly I think djvu is dead. Your documents are more likely to be readable in the future if you use PDF.

In any case, do not let me prevent you from trying. Maybe you can do a comparison and show us the benefits.

Comment: @Emre. djvu is not dead. It luck of user audience because most of digital book shops and reader producers avoid this format, but technically it is macho.

Comment: @Jasper Loy. Can you list how you get .djvu with free software tools stack?

Comment: @gavenkoa: Technical superiority is no guarantee of success (I am old enough to remember Betamax video recorders!)

Comment: @Emre I know that wikibooks prefers djvu for technical reasons, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Canageek PDF is a security hazard. It allows embedded JavaScript and Flash which there are many exploits for, particularly in the older versions of Flash bundled with older versions of Adobe Reader. If you don't use Adobe Reader, you're probably safe, because most other readers don't support active content.

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin Yes, but if you are just stripping the images and text out then you wouldn't be executing any javascript anyway.

Comment: @Emre Djvu uses JB2, which is apparently similar to JBIG2 for one of its compression layers. It is also supported by the Internet Archive's Million Books project, so it isn't totally dead.

Comment: djvu can produce documents with better quality/size ratio. And it also allows links and other advanced features, though not as many as pdf.  The main problem is that there are not free creators/editors, and it doesn't have the hype and support that pdf has.

Comment: In my experience, djvu viewing performance (using DjView4) is much, much better than any PDF viewer I've found.

Comment: djvu has many advantages with respect to pdf. First of all, two layer format for scans where the text and the background tone are separate and one can view in mode where background shades are erased/white etc. Second for most scanning systems djvu gives smaller files, and the files converted from tiff are usually smaller with the same clarity.

Comment: Third, each page in djvu is self-contained. In pdf pages often depend very much on layout in preamble of the whole document so you need special tools to export few pages or to merge documents and those often produce documents which render different than the selected pages in the original document. On djvu you can safely pick and match any choice of pages fro any number of documents and make a document for your purpose.

Comment: For example you study a course which used chapters and selected topics from wide literature. You make a new djvu book from just selected pages in a number of books with exact rendering and code of each page as in the original book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: You can't produce DjVu output from LaTeX code directly, just DVI, PS, or PDF. You would need a LaTeX compiler which is DjVu capable which doesn't exists yet and is very unlikely to be ever written. So, the only way to do this is to convert the produced PDF somehow to DjVu (I wouldn't go from DVI/PS). However, the topic PDF-to-DjVu would be off-topic here.

Comment: I had to convert `pdf` files to the `djvu` format before. IMHO the best option so far is the [pdf2djvu](http://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/) project.

Comment: @Paulo Cereda. Thanks for suggestion. `pdf2djvu` have build for Windows and present in Debian repo. And do job right!